# Including a non-class php file via namespace without using relative path

Tags: php, path, namespaces, include, composer-php

The problem I have been having for some time is including a "view" php file that resides in some location, known to the class whose method I am calling, but not necessarily to the place from which I am calling it. Best to explain it by example:

Say I have a file being included somewhere, that is responsible for rendering a table. Because there are many similar tables in my application, I use a separated file with template-like table view and if I want to change some aspects of it, I pass the needed parameters.

Here is said concrete view:

```
[MainView.php]


// Convert data from JSON.
/** @var $model MainDataModel */
$model = MainDataModel::rebuildFromJson($_POST["model"]);

// Prepare data for table view
/** @var $data TableViewData */
$data = new TableViewData();
$data->model = $model;
$data->tableBody = "MainTableBody.php";
$data->tableClass = "main-table";
$data->viewClass = "main-view";

/** Attach table. */
// include("../../Common/View/TableView.php"); (1)
include("../../../../vendor/composer/wb/Common/src/View/TableView.php"); (2)
```

and here is common TableView I want to pass the $data to and include to page:

```
[TableView.php]
namespace Common\Controller;

use ...

/** @var $data TableViewData  */
if (!(isset($data) && $data->checkForRequiredFields($data))) {
    return;
}

?>
<div class="<?php echo $data->viewClass; ?>">
    <div class="datatable">
        <table class="<?php echo $data->tableClass; ?>">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <?php /** @var $column ColumnModel */
                    foreach ($data->model->columns as $column): ?>
                       <th><?php echo $column->text ?></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="datatable-body">
                <?php include($data->tableBody); ?>
            </tbody>
         </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

All is fine (relatively) as long as I use include (1), but when I switched to composer I also separated the common classes and put them in some remote location, that I really should not care about.

In other words, something tells me I shouldn't need to have knowledge about exact path to TableView.php, relative to wherever I am using it and there probably has to be a better way to use it. Obviously, (2) doesn't quite work and I would actually be surprised if such a foolish way would have worked.

So now my question is: how could I include that view (TableView) without using relative path every time I use it? Something along the lines of including and accessing controller class (TableViewController?), which is in same directory as TableView and holds information about absolute positioning of the TableView?

Some way around the problem is also to make the class return the view and then call the class by namespace, but that's workaround, not the solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If it's just a matter of not having to specify the path, you can add the path of the directory containing the template files to the include path.

Comment: I use only namespaces via composer's autoloader most of the time and try to not use any paths if I can. If I use these common classes via namespaces I do not want to care about absolute paths. Even if I wanted to care about them, I am not sure how to include path to view attached via composer. In question I included example of include of such path and it failed to work, despite path being correct. Is there something else behind it?

Comment: You don't use anything worthy of namespaces in your view. And additionally, autoloading will not work here because there is no class inside that could be autoloaded. Also, I can't see anything that should have the need for the `use` as well. Best guess: When loading stuff, `__DIR__` will always tell you the directory your current file is in, and you can go from there with relative directions into your path - that would work independently of any relocation of your whole package.

Comment: It's true, namespaces in my views are mostly for cohesion and I didn't want to autoload view files, they are included or loaded via controllers. `use` is there so that IDE can recognize the types used  in @var annotation of phpdoc. Anyway, I have fiddled around with __DIR__-like things and couldn't manage them to work, but somehow I finally got it to run using the static method. [Sven](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1627406/sven): you can post your suggestion as an  answer and if nobody comes with some better, more generic solution for some time I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with various path functions and constants I've come to some solution of a problem. It's not too neat but nevertheless it works. Here it is:

```
[TableViewController.php]
(...)
public static function getTableViewPath() {
        return __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "View" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
            . "TableView.php";
    }  
(...)

[MainView.php]
(...)
/** Attach table. */
include(TableViewPresenter::getTableViewPath());
(...)
```